# Ensuring button takes focus within ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, button, windows-7, scrollviewer, arrow-keys

**Whoops!** Completely forgot about an application wide style I have, this is a margin on the button. I have modified the code and the gif to reflect this.

I have the following XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Name="SampleMainWindow1" x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300">
<DockPanel>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="40,40,40,40" Width="Auto">Button 1</Button>
                <Button Margin="40,40,40,40" Width="Auto">Button 2</Button>
                <Button Margin="40,40,40,40" Width="Auto">Button 3</Button>
                <Button Margin="40,40,40,40" Width="Auto">Button 4</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

However, when a button recieves focus such as `Button 1`, and I press the right key, I instantly focus on `Button 2`, however as you can see, I have to press right a few more times before `Button 3` recieves focus, and likewise for `Button 4`.

How can make it so that the keys instantly focus on the next button, and that button would scroll into view?

[image: Example]

Comment: Does it happens in Win7 OS? I tried it in Win8.1 it works as you expected.

Comment: Oh dear!... I'm sorry, I appear to have missed a vital point!!! Yes, this is occuring on Windows 7. My apologies, I didn't mention the OS as I thought the behaviour would be more dependant on the GUI framework rather than the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the panel to scroll by setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to true.

Comment: Simple answer, but that's exactly what I'm after. Bounty awarded, thank you. :)